# Смена стилей у элементов на странице?

Tags: javascript

Использую вот такую систему смены стилей по кнопке. Однако не все элементы меняют стили. Те, которых несколько на страницы не меняют стили. Подскажите как переделать код, чтобы все элементы меняли стили, даже которых несколько на странице.

```js
let bodyNight = document.querySelector('.body-night');
let breadcrumbNight = document.querySelector('.breadcrumb-night');
let breadcrumbSocialNight = document.querySelector('.breadcrumb-social-night');

let buttonTheme = document.querySelector('.night-user_theme');
// УСЛОВИЕ ЕСЛИ В ХРАНИЛИЩЕ С ЭТИМИ КЛАССАМИ НЕТ КЛАССА ACTIVE ТО ДО ДОБАВЛЯЕМ ЕГО

if (localStorage.getItem('body-night', 'breadcrumb-night', 'breadcrumb-social-night') == 'active') {
bodyNight.classList.add('active');
breadcrumbNight.classList.add('active');
breadcrumbSocialNight.classList.add('active');

}
   
buttonTheme.onclick = function() {
  bodyNight.classList.toggle('active');
  breadcrumbSocialNight.classList.toggle('active');
  breadcrumbNight.classList.toggle('active');


  if (localStorage.getItem('body-night', 'breadcrumb-night', 'breadcrumb-social-night') == 'active') {
  localStorage.removeItem("body-night", "active");
  localStorage.removeItem("breadcrumb-night", "active");
  localStorage.removeItem("breadcrumb-social-night", "active");

  } else {
  localStorage.setItem("body-night", "active");
  localStorage.setItem("breadcrumb-night", "active");
  localStorage.setItem("breadcrumb-social-night", "active");
 
  }
};
```

```html
<!-- Начало меню -->  
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4  col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> <!-- style="border: solid 1px green" -->
            <div class="panel panel-info hidden-xs">
              <div class="panel-heading panel-body-night"><div class="sidebar-heading">Поиск</div></div>
              <div class="panel-body panel-body-night">
                <form role="search" action="/search/" method="get">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="search" name="q_search" class="form-control input-night" placeholder="Ваш запрос">
                      <div class="input-group-btn">
                         <button class="btn btn-default btn-default-night" type="submit">
                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-info menu-panel_hidden">
              <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-night"><div class="sidebar-heading">Авторизация</div></div>
              <div class="panel-body panel-body-night">
                <?php if (!$this->dx_auth->is_logged_in()): ?>
                  
                
                <form role="form" action="/auth/login" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-night" placeholder="Логин" name="username">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-night" placeholder="Пароль" name="password">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-default-night col-lg-5"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Войти</button>
                  <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-lg-7 pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Регистрация</button> -->
                  <a href="/auth/register" class="btn btn-default btn-default-night col-lg-7 pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Регистрация...</a>
                </form>
                <?php else: ?>

                 <?php if($this->dx_auth->is_admin()): ?> 
                    Группа: админы <br>
                    Логин: <i class="fas fa-user-secret"></i> <?php echo $this->dx_auth->get_username(); ?><br>
                    Звание: Заслуженный модер СССР
                     <br>

                    <a href="/auth/logout" class="btn btn-default btn-default-night pull-right"><i class="fas fa-door-open"></i> Выход</a>
                  <?php else: ?>
                  
                    Группа: пользователи <br>
                    Логин: <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon_user"></i> <?php echo $this->dx_auth->get_username(); ?> <br>
                    Звание: Бродяга <br>
                    
                    <br>
                    <a href="/auth/logout" class="btn btn-default btn-default-night pull-right"><i class="fas fa-door-open"></i> Выход</a>

                  <?php endif ?>
                  
                <?php endif ?>
              </div>
            </div>

              <!-- ------------------------------>
              <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-night"><div class="sidebar-heading">Новости</div></div>
                <div class="panel-body panel-body-night news_color">

                  <?php foreach ($hotnews as $key => $value): ?>
                    <p><a href="/news/view/<?php echo $value['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $value['title']; ?></a></p>
                  <?php endforeach ?>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
          <!-- Конец меню -->
```

```css
:root {
  --bg-main-color: #22272b;
  --text-main-color: #bfbfbf;
  --body-main-color: #171c20;
}

.body-night.active {
 background-color: var(--body-main-color)!important;
}

.breadcrumb-social-night.active {
 background-color: var(--bg-main-color);
 border: 1px solid #393d41;
 color: var(--text-main-color)!important;
}

.breadcrumb-night.active {
 background-color: var(--bg-main-color);
 border: 1px solid #393d41;
}

.panel-body-night.active {
 background-color: var(--bg-main-color)!important;
 border: 1px solid #393d41!important;
 color: var(--text-main-color)!important;
}

.panel-body-night.active>p>a {
 color: var(--text-main-color)!important;
}
```

Comment: `querySelaectorAll(...).forEach(...)`

Comment: Прочитай про делегирование

Comment: @Alexfixer дайте пример html, чтобы можно было сделать наглядное пособие с Вашими данными.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Вставил HTML код

Comment: @Denis640Kb Для panel-heading-night не получается подобным образом установить новый стиль

Comment: @Alexfixer добавьте ещё Ваш css.

Comment: @Denis640Kb добавил и css

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете для выбора элементов на странице метод `document.querySelector`, но он выбирает первый попавшийся элемент со страницы с таким селектором.

Вам нужно заменить этот метод на `document.querySelectorAll` для элементов, которых должно быть несколько на странице *(метод `document.querySelectorAll` вернет Вам массив из DOM узлов)*.

Пример:

```
let bodyNight = document.querySelectorAll('.body-night');
let breadcrumbNight = document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb-night');
let breadcrumbSocialNight = document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb-social-night');

let buttonTheme = document.querySelectorAll('.night-user_theme');
// УСЛОВИЕ ЕСЛИ В ХРАНИЛИЩЕ С ЭТИМИ КЛАССАМИ НЕТ КЛАССА ACTIVE ТО ДО ДОБАВЛЯЕМ ЕГО

if (localStorage.getItem('body-night', 'breadcrumb-night', 'breadcrumb-social-night') == 'active') {
    bodyNight.forEach(item => item.classList.add('active'))
    breadcrumbNight.forEach(item => item.classList.add('active'))
    breadcrumbSocialNight.forEach(item => item.classList.add('active'))

}

buttonTheme.forEach(item => {
    item.onclick = function() {
        bodyNight.forEach(item => item.classList.toggle('active'))
        breadcrumbSocialNight.forEach(item => item.classList.toggle('active'))
        breadcrumbNight.forEach(item => item.classList.toggle('active'))


        if (localStorage.getItem('body-night', 'breadcrumb-night', 'breadcrumb-social-night') == 'active') {
            localStorage.removeItem("body-night", "active");
            localStorage.removeItem("breadcrumb-night", "active");
            localStorage.removeItem("breadcrumb-social-night", "active");

        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("body-night", "active");
            localStorage.setItem("breadcrumb-night", "active");
            localStorage.setItem("breadcrumb-social-night", "active");

        }
    }
})
```

Надеюсь, что это помогло.

Удачи!

Comment: пробовал и с document.querySelectorAll вместо  document.querySelector однако это не помогло

Comment: @Alexfixer вы проходили циклом по массиву с DOM-узлами?

Comment: нет, можете пример на моём случае показать?

Comment: @Alexfixer пример добавил в ответ

Comment: попробовал, элементы которые принимали стили по прежнему принимают, а panel-body-night по прежнему не меняет стиль, хотя в localstorage написано что panel-body-night active....

Comment: Попробовал ещё раз, не там скрипт подключил просто...Спасибо)